# Flexbox - Image and Content

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple flex container with 2 items; an image and the other is a small piece of descriptive text.

I'd like the image to grow and be as responsive as possible, but I also want there to be a max-height in place to avoid it growing too much. This causes a gap when the max-height is reached and the screen expands even further in width.

Is there a way to only have the container item fill the image as it grows so there are no gaps, or perhaps align the image to the left or the right side of the screen (self-align didn't appear to work)? I'm not sure what the answer to this is.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #FFEEDD;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.container>.image {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.container>.text {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/c/1500/2000">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus aliquid eius.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1**

> Get rid of

```
.container > .image {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**Solution #2**

```
.image{
  text-align:right;
}
```

**Solution #3** (*You were trying to achieve this one*)

All you needed was to add `flex`, direction to `column` and then align items to right by `flex-end`

```
.image{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-end;
  flex:1;
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #FFEEDD;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.container>.text {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/c/1500/2000">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus aliquid eius.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marked this as correct answer, because flex-grow: 1 on .image is what caused the headache! @Daniel provided an equally good answer, which also works. Apologies that I cannot up-vote you guys (have to be a certain rank for that privilege).

Comment: Just noticed that the image isn't being responsive in IE11 - it needed the fully formed `flex:` property, instead of `flex-grow:`. However, after doing this, Solution #3 still had problems in IE11 in terms of image responsiveness... the image was getting squashed in width when the screen size reduced. Is there any fix or workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align the text and image to the sides use `justify-content`:

```
.container {
  background-color: #FFEEDD;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxMOba)

Comment: You need to remove `flex-grow: 1` on `.image` for this solution to work.

Comment: Something I have noticed, and it's in the code on the question too... in IE11 the image isn't responsive like in other browsers such as Chrome. Is this feature not available, or is there a workaround?